# Pop up window / show as drop down

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

```
popupwindow_obj.showAsDropDown(clickbtn, -40, 18); // where u want show on view click event popupwindow.showAsDropDown(view, x, y);
```

Why is it that it is needed to specify absolute x and y co-ordinate values for pop up window object to be shown as drop down? Why does it eventhough not automatically show nearby of the control item that has been clicked enough, only for a one single time all though, once upon a time?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Never mind that these needs to specification of absolute x and y co-ordinate values are relative to be shown nearby of the control item only.

Comment: Has been - that has been clicked enough, only for a one single time all though, once upon a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the android docs:

**without cords**

> void showAsDropDown(View anchor) Display the content view in a popup
>   window anchored to the bottom-left corner of the anchor view.

**with cords:**

> void showAsDropDown(View anchor, int xoff, int yoff) Display the
>   content view in a popup window anchored to the bottom-left corner of
>   the anchor view offset by the specified x and y coordinates.

From these 2 methods we can learn that there are 2 (actually 3) `showAsDropDown` methods.

The one *without cords* will do what you want automatically in the bottom-left corner. And the one *with cords* will just take some offset from the bottom-left corner. the offset will be determined by you (`int xoff, int yoff`), `xoff` stands for x offset and `yoff` stands for y offset.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)